# Panel with Left - Middle - Right content with different result

Tags: html, css

How the result should look like: 
Left (static width) - Middle part should fill the content - Right (static width)

When jsFiddle is used there is a solution but in real website it does not work. In website it looks like when the style is set without CSS. But even if it is set in CSS it does not fill the middle part, it always overlaps left/right panels and takes 100% width of whole webpage.

**How it should look:**

```css
#ContentPanel1 {
    text-align:center
}
#ContentLeft1 {
    background:Yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
}
#ContentRight1 {
    background:Blue;
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
}
#ContentMiddle1 {
    text-align:left;
    background:Orange;
    margin:0 auto; 
    display:inline-block
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<br />
    <div id="ContentPanel1">
        <div id="ContentLeft1">
            This part should be displayed on left side              
        </div>
        <div id="ContentRight1">
            This part should be displayed on right side            
        </div>
        <div id="ContentMiddle1">
            This part should be fit into the middle of the other parts
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: How the result should look like]

**How it looks in IE and Firefox:**

```html
    <br />
    <div style="text-align: center;" id="ContentPanel1">
        <div id="ContentLeft1" style="background-color: Yellow; float: left; width: 80px;">
            This part should be displayed on left side                
        </div>
        <div id="ContentRight1" style="background-color: Blue; float: right; width: 80px;">
            This part should be displayed on right side             
        </div>
        <div id="ContentMiddle1" style="text-align: left; background-color: Orange; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
            This part should be fit into the middle of the other parts
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Panel width does not match]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css calc` for your propose. [Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) is the browser support for that.

```
#ContentPanel1 {
    text-align:center
}
#ContentLeft1 {
    background:Yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
}
#ContentRight1 {
    background:Blue;
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
}
#ContentMiddle1 {
    text-align:left;
    background:Orange;
    margin:0 auto; 
    display:inline-block
    width: calc(100% - 80px - 80px); // or width: calc(100% - 160px);
}
```

Comment: @Nasenbaer Does it fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with 'calc' function, the middle content have 100% - (both panel width).

```css
#ContentPanel1 {
    text-align:center
}
#ContentLeft1 {
    background:Yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
}
#ContentMiddle1 {
    background:Orange;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 160px);
}
#ContentRight1 {
    background:Blue;
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ContentPanel1">
  <div id="ContentLeft1">
    This part should be displayed on left side              
  </div>
  <div id="ContentMiddle1">
    This part should be fit into the middle of the other parts
  </div>
  <div id="ContentRight1">
    This part should be displayed on right side            
  </div>
</div>
```